Options for custom serial stream into Codesys
We have a Codesys instance running on a Raspberry Pi that we're going to use for motion control. To enact motion control, we need inputs from a number of sensors (accelerometers, position encoders, etc.) in a timely manner and for them to be somewhat synchronized. Typically, they're outputting a custom frame of the manufacturer's own design (i.e. vendor specific header and data bytes and data format) across RS-232 or RS-422 or similar.
To that end, I was hoping to get general options on getting those signals into the Codesys instance as variables to be used in motion calculations. Options we're aware of:

The CAA Serial and SysCom libraries in Codesys. We're currently bringing in some gyroscope positions via CAA Serial and a physical USB port; it works, but doesn't seem to be terribly efficient because we have to search for the header using a For loop and then manually group bytes to convert them to the appropriate numeric format.
We know about Codesys' shared memory example, but have yet to do more than just get it running.
Similar to this post, we've also looked into Ethercat conversion like the Beckoff EK1100 paired with an EL6001, but it seems that TwinCat may not be compatible with an RPi.
Placing another microcontroller in between the serial device and the PLC (RPi) to parse the frames into something that can have a "device description" written for it in Codesys, like i2c or something on the GPIO digital array.

Some of these solutions seem unnecessarily complex, some look like they may not work, and most require the manual addition of timestamps to ensure that we're comparing the right motion signals at the right time.
So are there other options available besides what's written above? Or is one of the above the simplest solution?

You may be able to use the EK1100 and EL6001 natively with Codesys.

@chrisbeardy - It did look like Beckoff had made some device description files for Codesys, but I don't have enough experience with that configuration to know if that's any more effective than operating directly with the serial port in Codesys ST; as in, the serial packets are exposed but I'd still have to write code to search and parse them within the actual control loop.
